# grid-template-rows: auto bug in safari

Tags: css, safari, css-grid

I am learning CSS Grid right now and encounter a 'bug' in safari

[Example code](https://codepen.io/nygma/pen/jZowZv)

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica, arial;
}

.full-size img {
  width: 100%;
}

article {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

header {
  background: deeppink;
  padding: 1rem;
}

main {
  background: whitesmoke;
  color: #444;
  padding: 1rem;
}

footer {
  background: purple;
  padding: 1rem;
}

* {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <header>
    Page Header
  </header>
  <main>
    <strong contenteditable>Hi, there's not much content, yet. You can write in here to expand the container.</strong>
    <figure class="full-size">
      <img src="http://www.book-a-flat.com/magazine/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Paris-8-appartement-toit-terrasse-piscine.jpg">
    </figure>
    <p>some text stuff...</p>
  </main>
  <footer>
    All rights reversed.
    <br>
    <small>I am always at the bottom of the page</small>
  </footer>
</article>
```

This is how the result looks in Safari:

[image: Safari screenshot]

This is how the result looks in Chrome:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

In order to make it work, I have added `grid-template-columns: 100%;` to the grid element, but in this guide, by [Mozila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) we have the following note:

> Note: `auto` track sizes (and only `auto` track sizes) can be stretched by
>   the `align-content` and `justify-content` properties.

So is the fix `grid-template-columns: 100%;` wrong, or is it a bug in Safari?

Comment: In which version of safari you seeing the issue? I tested in desktop and mobile versions - 8, 9, 10 and 11 but unable to reproduce it.

Comment: @GibinEalias I'm using Version 11.0.3 (13604.5.6), macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.3

Comment: Just checked on my phone and it does work as expected!

Comment: @GibinEalias it seems that in the snippet grid-template-columns: 100%; is not commented out

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, the issue is with the image used. The actual resolution of which is `1200x800`. However, the screens in which we are checking(MAC) is of a higher resolution, causing the image to stretch its height(to 1000px approx).

In Safari, seems like the `1fr` is calculated based on the actual image size and not the stretched one, causing the `1fr` to be computed to `800px`.

You can find the issue not appearing when you shrink the screen as the image won't stretch then. Also, that's the reason why we don't see the issue in an iPhone.

We can manually set the height to a `max-height` of `800px` to avoid it from stretching as a workaround to this issue. Or the solution of `grid-template-columns: 100%;` also holds good.

Hope this helps.